# boost::filesystem, std::getenv and concurrency

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo()
{
  const boost::filesystem::wpath& appdata_folder = std::getenv("APPDATA");
  while (true)
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::thread first(foo);
  boost::thread second(foo);

  first.join();
  second.join();
}
```

It fails at run-time with the following error:

> ***** Internal Program Error - assertion (codecvt_facet_ptr()) failed in const class std::codecvt &__cdecl
>   boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void):
>   libs\filesystem\src\path.cpp(888): codecvt_facet_ptr() facet hasn't
>   been properly initialized

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(std::getenv);k(getenv);k(DevLang-C%20%20);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true) I read that it's not thread-safe in terms of parallel set and get operations, not the several get operations as in my case. _wgetenv function works the same way.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

MSVC-12.0, boost 1.55, Windows 8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about printing the result of `getenv` in order to find out whether the error occurs in there (i.e. wrong string returned) or in boost?

Comment: @Janick Bernet std::getenv returns the correct result. This assertion came from boost sources because it's clearly stated in the assert message

Comment: An assert normally means wrong input. It could of course also have to do with some threading issue. But if you're definite the problem is in boost, why mention the whole `getenv` stuff then if you're sure it's in boost? That's just confusing then.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be bug reports around this for some versions of VS and boost: e.g. [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6320)

The suggestion is to initialise before your threads:

```
void make_loc(std::locale& loc)
{
    loc = default_locale();
}

int main()
{
    std::locale loc;

    boost::once_flag once;
    boost::call_once(once, boost::bind(&make_loc, boost::ref(loc)));
    //as you were
}
```